# How to have an auto filled field save into table?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

i've had a look around for an answer to this but couldn't find a definitive answer (if some can point me at a thread that does answer this i'd appreciate it).

I've created basic database where queries are logged and then reported on. When someone logs a new query it goes into a table called "TBL Main Log", this is done on a basic data entry form and when they select "Country" a field called "Owner" is auto populated. However, when i click save at the bottom, this data doesn't get pulled through into "TBL Main Log". My save is run off a basic close window and save macro.

I have set up my autofill being fed off a combo box for "Country". I'm assuming i need to do something in the event properties after update. I'm pretty limited with my coding abilities so could answers be dumbed down as much as possible for me.

Cheers

Luke

Comment: me.Refresh on forms forces bound controls to save to table. I have often had to include this on some user forms where users dont interact with it in the way I had envisioned.

Comment: Hi Doug, stupid question but where about would i put that in? Cheers

Comment: You should put it in the spot where you are certain the event is guaranteed to fire. Unfortuantely you need to answer that one for yourself.

Comment: Thanks Doug, Got it sorted now, i rewrote the event procedure that updated the 'Owner' field and it works. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hook me up with soem answer cred :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:

me.Refresh on forms forces bound controls to save to the table.